# How do you use dictionary in class?

Tags: python

I have to put name and student_num in dictionary.
the thing is I don't know how to call dictionary in class? how can i put name and student_num in that format?

```
class Cool():
    def __init__(self, name, student_num, new_dict):
        self._key = name
        self._value = student_num
        self._new_dict = new_dict


    def get_name(self):
        return self._key

    def get_student_number(self):
        return self._value

    def new_dict(self):
        return self._new_dict 

     #  I want to put name and student_name in this format:
     # {'name': 'student name'}
    def get_dict(self, new_dict):
        self._new_dict = {}
        self._new_dict[self._key] = self._value
        return self._new_dict[self._key]
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._new_dict[self._key])
```

Now when I test this code

```
>>>a = Cool({}, 'diana', 1234)
>>>print(a)
```

I get the following error:

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver_sandbox.py", line 20, in **str**
builtins.TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: the first parameter should be  `name` according to your definition, not a dictionary

Comment: You don't need—and shouldn't have—all those "getter" functions. Just access the attributes directly. This isn't Java.

Comment: @abarnert it is reasonable to use these getter functions. Because she is using protected variables with one underscore `_`, it it always better to get access these variables with function instead of variables directly

Comment: @ChesterL: No, because it is not reasonable to use protected variables in the first place. Again, this is not Java.

Comment: @abarnert I am talking using getter at the premise of protected variables, as for whether to use protected variables or not, it is up to the programmer.

Comment: @ChesterL: No, it's really not up to the programmer. Python has its own idioms—different from Java's, and a lot more strongly consistent—for good reasons. Ignoring them makes your code less readable. That doesn't mean you shouldn't violate them when you have a good reason, but it does mean you shouldn't violate them just for the hell of it. Read [Getters/Setters/Fuxors](http://tomayko.com/writings/getters-setters-fuxors), [Python is not Java](http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html), etc. Do not use protected variables and getters for no reason.

Comment: my point is, if you have protected variables for some reason, you'd better use getter@abarnert

Comment: I am not using it for no reason because later on I only need the name of the column and have to add two columns so that's why am using them

Answer (score 1):

You are calling cool incorrectly.

Try:

```
>>>a = Cool('diana', 1234, {})
```

Some more suggestions:

```
class Cool():
    def __init__(self, name, student_num, new_dict):
        self._key = name
        self._value = student_num
        self._new_dict = new_dict

    def get_name(self):
        return self._key

    def get_student_number(self):
        return self._value

    def get_dict(self):
        self._new_dict[self._key] = self._value
        return self._new_dict[self._key]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._new_dict[self._key])
```

In order to get `print` to work (the way the code is currently). You need to first call get_dict.

You could just do the following:

```
a = Cool('diana', 1234, {})
print(a.get_dict())
```

or you could edit your code to handle the dict earlier.

Comment: Thank you so much but I am still getting an error:ile "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.0\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 18, in __str__
builtins.KeyError: 'diana'

Comment: You are never calling get_dict. I will update anwser.

Comment: Oh yeah i completely forgot about that but now another problem came: it says get_dict() missing 1 required positional argument: 'new_dict'

Comment: @Diana Make sure to update get_dict to look like the one in the example.

Answer (score 0):

To your edited question,

```
>>>a = Cool({}, 'diana', 1234)
```

does this:

```
class Cool():
    def __init__(self, name, student_num, new_dict):

        self._key = name            # name is {}
        self._value = student_num   # student_num is 'diana'
        self._new_dict = new_dict   # new_dict is 1234
```

Then

```
>>print(a)
```

does this:

```
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self._new_dict[self._key])

    => _new_dict is 1234
    => return 1234[self._key]
    => self._key is {}
    => return 1234[{}]
    => TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

`something[]` is a subscript, a slice, operation, and Python can't do that with numbers.

It's not clear to me what the whole code should do, but it looks like several times more code than it needs to be. I assume some of this is mandated by the assignment requirements?

Are you creating one "Cool" class per student? Or one "Cool" class for many students? It looks at the moment like that's not certain - if it's one Cool class per student, putting one name in a dictionary and taking it out again doesn't add anything to the class. If it's one Cool class for a lot of students, then `get_name` makes no sense because there will be many names and `get_student_number` will need a way to identify which student.